# Yii2 query with DateTime data returns more data than expected

Tags: php, date, datetime, yii2, dateinterval

I want to know the amount of instances that have been published in the last 10 days.

This is what I wrote:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$meno_dieci_giorni = $date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));


$ultime_iniziative = Iniziativa::find()
        ->where(['>=' , 'ym_published_date' , $meno_dieci_giorni]) 
       ->count();
```

and this is what I do when I try to retrieve:

```
if ($ultime_iniziative > 0) {
 #do something 
}
```

but It returns more data than expected.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi. Maybe there you have a status and must add it to filter also? What is you table structure?

Comment: This is the table structure  
```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "iniziativa".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string|null $ym_title
 * @property string|null $img
 * @property string|null $abstract
 * @property string|null $descrizione
 * @property string|null $ts_created
 * @property string|null $ym_slug
 * @property int|null $ym_template_id
 * @property int|null $ym_status
 * @property int|null $ym_active
 * @property string|null $ym_published_date
 * @property string|null $ym_trashed_date
```

Comment: How do you detected that is there more data than should be, do you have some kind a reference? If yes you should look at the query used to get the data, as I see you have some kind of statuses like attributes: `ym_status`, `ym_active` but you don't used it in the query